# how to call MySql Stored procedure multiple time with multiple parameter.

Tags: mysql, procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NearBy(IN VarLat VARCHAR(20), IN VarLng VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
SELECT CustId,address, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(VarLat) ) * cos( radians( Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( Longitude ) - radians(VarLng) ) + sin( radians(VarLat) ) * sin( radians( Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM ordermaster HAVING distance < 0.02 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10;

END;

call NearBy('21.1021258','79.0659928')
```

this my procedure to find nearby customer. parameter are lat and lng. 
latitude and longitude are stored in database table. 
i want result like no of order are coming form particular area of radius of 20 meter.

Comment: So what would you like to get out of whatever code you need?  Some example data and expected results might help.

Comment: in want this procedure call repeatedly and shows count of orders coming from particular region. and longitude and latitude are taken from table which are already available.

Comment: If the parameters are available in a table, why not just do a join using the formula?